# how to stop middleware chain?

Tags: node.js, express

How can I properly end a middleware chain in case of error ?

In my code I have

```
    if (someProblem) {
        res.status(statuscode).json({message: 'oops'});
        return;
    }
```

Yet the midleware in the chain after that keeps getting called giving me the `Can't set headers after they are sent`error.

Comment: chain only can happen if you call next, else it will be stop

Comment: you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Middleware does not advance on its own.  It only goes to the next step in the chain when you call `next()` so as long as you don't call `next()`, then the next step will not execute.

So, if you just send a response and return (without calling `next()`), then you should not have an issue.

The code you show in your question would not, all by itself, cause the error message you refer to so there must be more going on that you aren't showing us for that error to occur.

Comment: what happens to memory exactly? will it leak?

Comment: @AiShiguang - No issues with memory.  Sending the response will finish the http connection and close it.  Request handlers are just a static array of function references that is consulted when `next()` is called to find the next one in the chain.  Skipping some of those functions doesn't change memory usage in any way.

Comment: @jfriend00, what about calling `next(false)`? According to the restify docs, it's supposed to terminate the chain but it still throws the error that the op got

Comment: @peterchaula - First, restify isn't the same as Express.  In express, you can do four things with `next()`.  1) You can send a response and not call `next()` at all. 
 That finishes the request and stops further routing.  2) You can do just plain `next()` which advances to the next route in the chain.  3) You can call `next('route')` to bypass all the rest of the routes in this router and continue routing in other routers.  4) You can do `next(err)` which will stop any further routing and pass an error to your default error handler which will send an error response.

Answer (score 3):

So you simply have to attach an errorHandler (which is a function that takes 4 parameters) before you create the actual server instance.

Anywhere in the app you can now simply create an error with `var newError = new Error('my error message');` and pass it to the `next` callback with `next(newError);` 
To stop the execution after the error has been thrown and to not send a response twice use `return next (newError);`

```
// example route
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
  if (someProblem) {
    var newError = new Error('oops');
    return next(newError);
  }
  res.send('all OK - no errors');
});

// attach this errorHandler just before you create the server
app.use(function(error, req, res, next){
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).json(error);
});

// this is where you create the server
var server = app.listen(4000, function(){
 console.log('server started');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your middleware to not go to the next step of the chain but to return the error you have to call `next(error)` callback.

This will call the error handler middleware where you can operate with the error and return it to the client if thats what you want.

To implement your custom error handler middleware you can use `handleError(err, req, res, next)(error, req, res, next)`