# nodejs middleware execution continues after return

Tags: node.js, middleware

I have the following middleware:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const keys = Object.keys(req.params);
  keys.forEach(elem => {
    if (
      (elem.includes('id') || elem.includes('Id')) &&
      !mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params[elem])
    )
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: `id: ${req.params[elem]} is invalid` });
  });
  next();
};
```

it is called in a get request:

```
// @route   GET api/movies/:id
// @desc    Get a movie with specified id from db
// @access  Public
router.get('/:id', checkId, async (req, res) => {
const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id);
res.json(movie);
});
```

When I make a request in postman with an invalid id (ex: 1234) I recieve the proper response being 400 with msg: 'id 1234 is invalid' yet the execution still passes to the reqest callback code and an error is thrown as I try to access db with invalid id.

so the question is why does the middleware still allow the execution of next() even if it already returned with the 400?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop middleware chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922900/how-to-stop-middleware-chain)

Comment: You are returning http response in a loop! Better to write a promise and reject on invalidation, then handle the promise.

Comment: Your main question answer is: Because of Asynchronous nature of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the router that there was a problem by calling `next("some-error")`.  For example, you could do this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const keys = Object.keys(req.params);
  keys.forEach(elem => {
    if (
      (elem.includes('id') || elem.includes('Id')) &&
      !mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params[elem])
    ) {
      res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: `id: ${req.params[elem]} is invalid` });
      return next("invalidinput");
    }
  });
  next();
};
```

Or you could be more generic by setting the result outside in the router if you like, like this:

In your middleware:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const keys = Object.keys(req.params);
  keys.forEach(elem => {
    if (
      (elem.includes('id') || elem.includes('Id')) &&
      !mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params[elem])
    ) {
      // === Report the error and let the router handle it
      return next({
        type: "invalidinput",
        msg: `id: ${req.params[elem]} is invalid`
      );  
    }
  });
  next();
};
```

Then at the bottom in your router:

```
// handle any errors
router.use(err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.type === "invalidinput") {
      return req.status(400).json({msg: err.msg});
    }
    else {
      return res.status(500).json({msg: "Internal error."});
    }
  }
  return next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another possible solution here is to convert the forEach to a classical for loop, thu making this middleware run synschronously

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const keys = Object.keys(req.params);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (
      (keys[i].includes('id') || keys[i].includes('Id')) &&
      !mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params[keys[i]])
    )
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: `id: ${req.params[keys[i]]} is invalid` });
  }
  next();
};
```